# How to run more then one feature into one junit test with cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm

I have 2 feature files with different tags(@tag_1 and @tag_2). Also, I have junit test class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = path/to/features, tags = {"@tag_1", "@tag_2"})
```

But if I run junit test, in console I see this:

> 0 scenarios
>   
> 0 steps
> None of the features at [path/to/features] matched the filters: [@tag_1, @tag_2]

But in features I see these tags before Feature word

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look to cucumber tags [specifications](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags):

> - Tags which are comma separated are ORed
> - Tags which are passed in separate —tags are ANDed

Translated to cucumber-jvm:

- If you want to do an **OR** (run features annotated with @tag1 or @tag2)

  @CucumberOptions(features = path/to/features, tags = {"@tag_1, @tag_2"})
- If you want to do an **AND** (run features annotated with both @tag1 and @tag2)

  @CucumberOptions(features = path/to/features, tags = {"@tag_1", "@tag_2"})

Hope it helps.