# How to implement AND OR relation in Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have a feature file which looks like below :

```
Feature: This is a sample feature file
@tag1
    Scenario: This is a scenario one.
        Given scenario one
        When @tag1
        Then execute @tag1
@tag2   
    Scenario: This is a scenario two.
        Given scenario two
        When @tag2
        Then execute @tag2

@tag3
    Scenario: This is a scenario three.
        Given scenario three
        When @tag3
        Then execute @tag3  
@tag2 @tag3
    Scenario: This is a scenario two and three.
        Given scenario two and three
        When @tag2 @tag3
        Then execute @tag2 @tag3
```

Now I need to run only `@tag1` and `@tag2 @tag3` not to run single `@tag2` and single `@tag3` tag

So how can I mention the tags on `@CucumberOptions` by which only `@tag1` and `@tag2 @tag3` scenario will run other will not run.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269206/how-to-run-more-then-one-feature-into-one-junit-test-with-cucumber-jvm/32437621#32437621) could help you.

Comment: It appears you are following an imperative style of BDD which will lead to no end of problems.  You should be learn the declarative style and your need for AND/OR will go away and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new tag to represent the combination of 2 and 3, e.g. `@tag2and3`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I donot want to create any new tag.I am just try to use AND OR logic here.

Comment: I know, but looking at the source for the Cucumber JUnit runner I'm not sure you can. It looks like it just feeds a list of tags to the runner, which then looks for any scenario with one of the tags.